# Validar datos de los inputs usando DTOs en Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Estoy trabajando con DTOs en symfony y quiero validar a la hora de enviar el DTO que todos los campos cumplan con su restricción (longitud,tipo,etc).
Ya realizo la validación con Form type a nivel HTML pero quiero validar tambien a la hora de enviar el DTO para que el servidor reciba de manera correcta todos los campos.
Estuve investigando y encontré esta propuesta:

```
    $json = $request->getContent();
    $class = $configuration->getClass();

    //Try to deserialize the request dto
    try {
        $dto = $this->serializer->deserialize($json, $class, AppConstants::API_SERIALIZE_FORMAT);
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        $jsonMessage = $this->customValidationServiceProvider->getJsonErrorMessage(json_last_error());
        throw new JsonException($e->getMessage() . ' more info:' . $jsonMessage);
    }
```

DTO

```
 /**
 * @var string valid Email
 * @Assert\NotNull
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Email Address required")
 * @Assert\Email(message="Invalid Email Address")
 * @JMS\Type("string")
 * @JMS\SerializedName("email")
 */
public $email;
```

Asi esta bien? O hay alguna forma que sea mejor?